# Is the %{HTTPS} variable on whenever https is specified in the URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, httpd

From Apache HTTP Server's manual, it mentioned

> Will contain the text "on" if the connection is using SSL/TLS.

Does it mean it is "on" ONLY when the SSL/TLS connection is fully established with handshake completed successfully? Or does it mean it is "on" as long as the requester specify "https" in the URL and initiated a SSL/TLS connection?

Because I have many VHs (some http, some https) and want to save effort by putting a conditional check outside & before all VH using %{HTTPS} to add the Strict Transport Security response header. I wonder if requester specified "https" in the URL for a VH which does not support https, will the conditional check still add the Strict Transport Security header in the error response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if requester specified "https" in the URL for a VH which does not support https, will the conditional check still add the Strict Transport Security header in the error response.

If the Virtual Host does not support HTTPS then the connection will fail and the browser will not get a HTTP response so can not get back any HTTP headers.

So yes you are safe to add HSTS based on that HTTPS variable.

Or if still worried then just add it to the HTTPS Virtual Host config rather than at top level config. That’s my preferred option as allows different HSTS headers per virtual host (e.g. if you are not ready to use `includeSubDomain` attribute at top level domain due to some sub domains still not being available on HTTPS yet).